# Split cell into Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would ask a question about splitting cell into Excel.
I can split cell (for example diagonally) and want to use one from numbers as reference to next cell calculation (also for splitted cell).

Thanks and regards
Stas

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you manage to split a cell diagonally???

Comment: I need to take 8 from A2 right cell and use it on A3 left cell.

Comment: I as DBA not know if this possible. Thanks for question and quick answer.

Comment: Is that just a diagonal border in cell `A2`? If so, just use a function like `TEXTSPLIT()` to retrieve values on either side of whatever character is pushing 9 and 8 apart.

Comment: Thanks, but if I will use TEXTSPLIT I can not enter second value into cell. I mean this function will calculate 8 into next cell (also separate with diagonal) only.

Comment: I mean I need use next cell for adding some other values. TEXTSPLIT (as you explaned) will calculate result and I need this cell for next day adding value.

Comment: What? Can you be more clear?

Comment: In my example as you see, in cell A2 I have two values 9(left side) and 8(right side). I need fill into A3 cell value 8 (yesterday value, that received from you advise using TEXTSPLIT function ) and on evening I need add future value (for example 6.

Comment: All cell need keep 2 value - morning and evening calculation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, splitting cells is impossible in Excel, unless, obviously, the cell consists of the merge of other cells.

So I would state that what you're trying to do is impossible.

**Edit:**

Based on [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)'s comment I have managed showing something similar in an Excel file, but it is really bogus:

[image: screenshot]

As you see I have created a diagonal border, which is placed inside the cell, and in the cell, I have put the single value `1             2` (just a one and a two and a bunch of spaces in between).

As you see this has nothing to do with splitting cells, it's just a very weird way to display weird values :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have used a [diagonal border](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4869-excel-split-a-cell-diagonally.html) and have mistaken this ***formatting*** as some technique of 'spliting' a cell you could just split the cell's content by whatever characters are pushing the numbers apart in the cell:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=--TEXTBEFORE(A1," ")
```

Or, to retrieve 2;

```
=--TEXTAFTER(A1," ")
```

Comment: I believe I have Excel 365 but no `TextBefore()` function. What version Excel supports that?

Comment: Hm I thought it's currently released to the current channel. Should be available. Did you try an update? @Dominique

Comment: I'm having version 2003, build 12527.22286). When trying an update something went wrong.